Create parent groups from child data grouped into ranges
I have several columns. Each has it's own grouping of consecutive sequences. I would like to create a parent group based on those smaller groups. The following is a small example of what I am attempting to accomplish. The data represents Teams that can belong to different Departments, that can belong to different Companies.
Given the table:
company_id    department_id    team_id
1             101              10
1             101              11
1             101              12
1             102              10
1             102              11
1             102              12
2             101              10
2             101              11
2             101              12
2             102              10
2             102              11
2             102              12

The desired results:
company_ids   department_ids   team_ids
1-2           101-102          10-12

As you can see, this represents the data in a more concise manner.
Likewise, I also need to account for gaps. Because not all Teams will overlap all Departments; and not all Departments will overlap all Companies. Given this example table:
company_id    department_id    team_id
1             101              10
1             101              11
1             101              12
1             102              10
1             102              11
1             102              12
2             101              10
2             101              11
2             101              12
2             102              10
2             102              11
<last record removed>

Desired results:
company_ids   department_ids   team_ids
1-1           101-102          10-12
2-2           101-101          10-12
2-2           102-102          10-11

The precedence of the resulting groups is not extremely important. For example, the previous results are synonymous with:
company_ids   department_ids   team_ids
1-2           101-102          10-11
1-1           101-102          12-12
2-2           101-101          12-12


Have you made any attempt at creating the desired outputs yourself yet, and gotten stuck somewhere?

from your data,
we have to filter company_id's and their respective department_id and team_id,then again need to filter unique data from department_id with their respective team_id's.Then again one more filtering to get higher and lower team_id's.
I think from backside means filtering from team_id's and then department_id's then company_id's will make easy process for you to solve this.
